# BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan is not working with filter

Tags: android

```
private UUID[] RX_SERVICE_UUID = new UUID[1]; 
RX_SERVICE_UUID[0] = UUID.fromString("0000e4eee-1112-1111-1111-14addb4as215");
```

when i am using the function with UUID `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(RX_SERVICE_UUID,mLeScanCallback)` method. It is not scanning the device when i am using without UUID means `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback)` then it is scanning the device. Please suggest.

Comment: it likely means that it can't find the device with required service. Probably your device does not run that service

Comment: Thanks for reply. it is running same service checked by another app.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are testing app in marshmallow

for scaning any ble device required some permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" />
```

**enable bluetooth**

```
 // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        mLeDevicePairedListAdapter = new LeDevicePairedListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        setPairedListAdapter(mLeDevicePairedListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
```

**start scaning by using this method**

```
 private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mScanning = true;
            selectedPositions = new ArrayList<>();
            pairselectedPositions = new ArrayList<>();
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
//        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

**callbackresponse**

// Device scan callback.

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//if device bounded then added another list and not bound then using other list diplay in list
                        if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                            mLeDevicePairedListAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
                        } else {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```